# How to check if EKCalendar is visible

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, icloud

I run in the situation that at least local calendars of type EKCalendarTypeLocal are listed by EKEventStore but arent't shown and can not be selected in the calendar app on iOS.

```
if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarsForEntityType:)]) cals = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
else cals = eventStore.calendars;
```

I found out that it has probably something to do with iCloud [Accessing programmatically created calendar on iOS device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932430/accessing-programmatically-created-calendar-on-ios-device).
I also created a local calendar successfully and could add events to it. This created calendar was not listed by EKEventStore but I get it with its identifier:

```
aCal = [eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:calId];
```

After I removed the iCloud account in the testing device all local calendars are shown also my own created. Is there any possibility to check if local calendars are hidden? So I can wrote an info text or hide them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have u solved?

Anyway, i'll try to answer.

As i understand iCloud don't let local calendars to be shown. If u turn of iCloud and then lead him back to on u will see a message like "Would u like to add your local calendar to iCloud?", so ... if the problem is just see the calendars in iCloud, extract your EKCalendar and change source in a EKSourceTypeCalDAV instead than EKSourceTypeLocal ... should be ok

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please provide a code example?

Comment: thanks for the welcome :) Please see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869118/ios-ekevent-store-recreating-icloud-calendars-in-a-loop-wont-save-local/13991658#13991658